# Make users in custom metadata type to change case status to 1) proceed and 2) decision in apex trigger

Tags: custom-metadata

I have created Custom metadata that will store the federation Id of the Users who can close cases. I will need to write a trigger to allow these users to change the status of the case 1) proceed and 2) decision in apex trigger. Those who can close the case are the users who has federation Id store in custom metadata types. Do you have an idea how to do that?

Comment: Please do not repost questions that have been closed. Instead, **edit** your existing posts to improve them. See our [tour] and [ask] to learn about our expectations for questions. If you're new to writing Apex triggers, I recommend starting with Trailhead. SFSE may be able to help when you get stuck.

Comment: I have edited it but no one is answering the question and I cannot tag anyone

Comment: The SFSE community is generally very good about answering detailed questions that meet our requirements. Again, please take some time to read the help topics I've linked above and improve your question by showing us what you've tried and where you're stuck. Providing complete implementations or step-by-step instructions are not the goals of this community, but I think you'll find our contributors are very generous with their help once you get started.